# Browser not visible when running selenium test with jenkins set up with tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jenkins

We are running jenkins with Tomcat. When we try to run the selenium web driver with a jenkins job, Nothing happens. We are unable to see the browser opening on the jenkins machine but we don't get any errors. On running the same code with eclipse on the same machine, the browser opens up fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Windows services -- including those run with the option "Allow service to interact with desktop" in Windows XP and Vista -- do not have access to many of the computer's resources, including the console display.  This may cause Automated GUI Tests to fail if you are running Apache Tomcat as a Windows Service and are doing any GUI testing.

This limitation can be resolved by not running Tomcat as a Windows Service, but instead through a "Scheduled Task" as an Application that runs at logon. There are several options for doing this, an example would be  to run "$TOMCAT_HOME\bin\tomcat5.exe".  When setting up the scheduled task in Windows Vista consider choosing the check-box for "Run with highest privileges" from the general tab, as this removes the need to always provide administrator privileges and may resolve other issues as well.

Answer (score 1):

In the case that you are running Jenkins as a windows service, you should either activate the checkbox `"Allow service to interact with desktop"` on the service, or just run it from the console with `"java -jar jenkins.war"`

Comment: Thanks for the reply John. We have already checked "Allow service to interact with desktop" but we don't wish to run it from console. Is there any other suggestion for this?

Comment: Run Jenkins as a service in the background it won't open apps in the foreground. You may either try to run it not as a service in the foreground, or run it as a Local System account and check Allow the service to interact with desktop option. In the latter case you may get into permission problem